# Django RelatedManager converts tuple to Unicode string?

Tags: python, django

To help myself learn Python, I'm writing a simple issue tracker using Django.

I have two simple classes (left some code out for brevity), `Issue` and `Version`

There is an `ISSUE_STATE` tuple that is used to maintain an `Issue`'s state:

```
ISSUE_STATE = (
    ('p', 'In Progress'),
    ('o', 'Open'),
    ('r', 'Resolved'),
    ('c', 'Closed'),
)
```

It's maintained in the `Issue` like so:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ISSUE_STATE)
    fix_version = models.ForeignKey(Version, related_name='issuesAsFix', null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

(As you can also see, a `Version` maintains a list of `Issue` objects.)

**The problem:**

When I access the state of an individual `Issue` instance, it's returned as a tuple. When I access the state of an `Issue` as provided by a `Version` object, it's returned as a Unicode string:

```
>>> v = Version()
>>> v.save()

>>> i = Issue()
>>> i.fix_version = v
>>> i.state = ISSUE_STATE[1]
>>> i.save()

>>> i.state
('o', 'Open')
>>> v.issuesAsFix.all()[0].state
u"('o', 'Open')"

>>> i == v.issuesAsFix.all()[0]
True
>>> i is v.issuesAsFix.all()[0]
False
```

Why is the `state` variable of the `Issue` a string when accessed as a child property of the `Version`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> >>> i.state = ISSUE_STATE[1]
> ```

This line is incorrect. It should be:

```
>>> i.state = ISSUE_STATE[1][0]
```

Comment: So the `state` variable shouldn't actually point to the tuple, rather just to the 'key' of the tuple, that single character?

Comment: Correct. The ORM will DTRT with respect to it.

Comment: All right. One piece of the puzzle that confuses me is that even though the `max_length` of the `CharField` is set to `1`, the entire Unicode string was stored in the database, instead of just the first character. Is this only enforced at the view/form level, and not when using the shell?